# How to draw the four conic sections

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw the four of geometry of conic sections from TikZ, circle parabola ellipse and hyperbola. I want 3D bi-cones figure like this:[conic sections](http://lh6.ggpht.com/-QlPR2LJwMIo/SwG06HzEfcI/AAAAAAAAAEA/Pp7RaURjYXg/s1280/conic%2520sections.jpg) for my student in analytic geometry.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, looking in the [`pgfmanual`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) will give you direct constructions for at least three of these.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10001/can-one-draw-a-hyperbola-with-arguments-in-tikz

Comment: to any close voters: based on the thousands of other `tikz` questions we have had on this site that have shown the same amount of effort and have been upvoted highly, I propose we leave this question open.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show what you've tried so far and what aspect of the figure you're struggling with?

Comment: In addition to @cmhughes comment. Please at least wait a week to give the OP to edit the question. There is no rush.

Answer (score 6):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{plotpoints=100,algebraic,polarplot}
\pstVerb{/LL 2 def}
\begin{document}
\multido{\r=.0+.1}{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \pstVerb{/EE \r\space def}%
    \psplot{0}{TwoPi}{LL/(1-EE*cos(x))}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit:

PSTricks' blog has a special page about conic section in 3D, visit [the blog here](http://pstricks.blogspot.com/2011/07/sections-coniques.html) but it was written in French.

Comment: I guess the OP wants to draw the origin of these curve in intersections … like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Conic_Sections.svg/713px-Conic_Sections.svg.png

Comment: @Tobi: I think so. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your pst-plot code and suggest blog, I want TikZ or pgfplot for my student in analytic geometry (output same in the blog). Thanks

Comment: I want 3D bi-cones figure like this:!http://lh6.ggpht.com/-QlPR2LJwMIo/SwG06HzEfcI/AAAAAAAAAEA/Pp7RaURjYXg/s1280/conic%2520sections.jpg

Comment: @somkiat_t: You should edit your question to include that information (and really, you should have already specified that when you first asked the question). Please also show what you've tried so far and what aspect of the figure you're struggling with.